# Finding $\lambda$ for $u(x)= \lambda u(\frac{x}{2})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Given:
>   1. Function $u(x)$ is infinitely differentiable and $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$
>   2. Identity ①: $u(x)= \lambda \cdot u\left(\dfrac x2\right)$.
>   Find all $\lambda$, for which ① is true for all x in R.

Could you kindly check the solution and point out where it is wrong or unclear? My assumption was that all $\lambda$ are of a $2^n$ kind where $\space n \in \{\Bbb{Z^+} \cup 0\}$.

Here is an attempt for a solution so far: If $u(x)=\lambda u\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$ then
\begin{align}
u(x)& = \lambda u\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
\lambda u\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) 
& = \lambda ^2 u\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\\
\lambda ^2 u\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)
& = \lambda ^3 u\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
\lambda ^{n-1} u\left(\frac{x}{2^{n-1}}\right)
& = \lambda ^n u\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\\
\implies u(x) &= \lambda ^n u\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) \tag*{②}
\end{align}
Now consider derivatives:
\begin{align}
u'(x)& = \frac{\lambda}{2} u'(\frac{x}{2})\\
u''(x)& = \frac{\lambda}{2^2} u''(\frac{x}{2})\\
u'''(x)& = \frac{\lambda}{2^3} u'''(\frac{x}{2})\\
& ...\\
u^{(n)}(x)& = \frac{\lambda}{2^n} u^{(n)} (\frac{x}{2^n})\\
\implies u^{(n)}(x)&= \left(\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)^n \space u^{(n)} \left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) \tag*{③}\\
\end{align}
which we come to after repeating the last equation similarly to ②.

$\lambda=1$ from ② implies $u(x)=a$ for $a \in \Bbb{R}$, and $|\lambda| < 1$ from ② implies $u(x) \to 0$ and thus $u(x) = 0$ for all $x$. (Is this line  correct?)

I am a bit lost with the logic in the line below:

$u(0) \ne 0$,
$\dfrac{u(x)}{\lambda^n}
\to u(0)
$ when 
$|\lambda| > 1 \implies $,
$\dfrac{u(x)}{\lambda^n} \to 0 \quad$
contradicts
$\quad u(0) \ne 0$.

now we have:

$u(0) = u'(0) = u''(0) = \cdots = u^{(n+1)} = 0\implies$ using Taylor for $u(0)=0$

$u(x) = xu'(0)+O(x^2)$

$u\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = x\frac{u'(0)}{2^n} + 
O\left(\frac{x^2}{4^n}\right)$
by using ②

$u(x)
=\lambda^n\left(x\frac{u'(0)}{2^n}+O\left(\frac{x^2}{4^n}\right)\right)$

$u(x)=\left(\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)^n xu'(0) + 
O\left(x^2\left(\frac{\lambda}{4}\right)^n\right)$.

in this equation

now let us apply 
$|\lambda| < 2 \implies u(x) \to 0$

$|\lambda| > 2 \implies u(x) \to \infty$.

$\therefore \lambda = 2$.

finally, applying the above procedure to the $(n)^{th}$ derivative of $u(x)$ and using ③

$u^{(n)}(x)=\left(\frac{\lambda}{2^n}\right)^n x\left(u^{(n+1)}(0)\right) + 
O\left(x^2\left(\frac{\lambda}{4^n}\right)^n\right)$.

we obtain that the $\lambda$ are all of a $2^n$ kind

Please feel free to point out the mistakes and\or missing parts.

P.S. If someone is interested there is also a more generalized version of this question on $K$ dimensions.

Comment: This seems to be related to, or a duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195478/solve-fx-c-times-f-fracx2-for-c

Comment: Ye, right, I put all the ideas together in one qtn

Comment: @CheungJoonHee: What is the domain of definition of $u$? Is it the whole $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlexM. Depends on funct, any infinitely differentiable works. Could be arcsin for example

Comment: @CheungJoonHee: May we at least assume that $0$ belongs to the domain of definition $D$? (In principle, it may happen that $0 \in \partial D$, and this would complicate the analysis.)

Comment: @AlexM. We might, it could help to develop the soln for arbitrary domain not containing 0. I still reckon the domain is R tbh.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable and satisfies $u(x) = \lambda u(x/2)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. We also assume that $u$ is not identically zero, to investigate non-trivial solutions.

- If $|\lambda| < 1$, then $u(x) = \lambda^k u(x/2^k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, hence $u$ is identically zero, which contradicts our assumption. We henceforth assume that $|\lambda| \geq 1$.
- For any integer $N \geq 0$,

  $$ u^{(N)}(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2^N} u^{(N)}(x/2). $$

  Pick $N$ large that $|\lambda| < 2^N$. Then this implies $u^{(N)}(x) = (\lambda/2^N)^k u^{(N)}(x/2^k) \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. So $u^{(N)}$ is identically zero, and therefore $u$ is polynomial.
- Since $u$ is a non-zero polynomial, we have

  $$ \lambda = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{u(x)}{u(x/2)} = 2^d, $$

  where $d$ is the degree of $u$.
- Finally, pick any $a \neq 0$ so that $u(a) \neq 0$. If we set $c = u(a)/a^d$, then

  $$u(2^k a) = \lambda^k u(a) = c (2^k a)^d $$

  for all $k \geq 0$. Since both $u(x)$ and $cx^d$ are polynomials which coincide for infinitely many values of $x$, it follows that $u(x) = cx^d$.

The converse is trivial. Summarizing:

> **Proposition.** Let $u : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$-function which is not identically zero and $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad u(x) = \lambda u(x/2)$$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $u(x) = cx^d$ and $\lambda = 2^d$ for some $c \neq 0$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @CheungJoonHee, $u(x) = \sqrt{x}$, or even $u(x) = |x|^{1/2}$, is not infinitely differentiable near $0$.

Comment: may you specify how was the $u(x) = cx^d$ obtained? it was said that if we set c so that $ca^d=u(a)$, but doesn't this mean that u(x) could be other than $cx^d$

Comment: @CheungJoonHee, My solution does show that any solution must take the form $u(x) = cx^d$. In my last step, I pick a single point $a$ at which $u(a) \neq 0$ holds and simply choose my constant $c $ to satisfy $ca^d = u(a)$. So, at this point I am claiming nothing about the form of $u(x)$ as function. What I showed then is, the equation $u(x) = cx^d$ has infinitely many solutions, which are of the form $2^k a$ for $k \geq 0$. This renders $u(x) - cx^d$ a polynomial which vanishes at infinitely many points, hence $u(x) - cx^d$ is a zero polynomial and $u(x) = cx^d$ identically.